# No encuentro la ruta /var/lib/docker/volumes en mi linux - Docker

Tags: linux, docker, rutas, wsl

Hola buenas tardes muchachos, no entiedo porque al ingresar desde la terminal a la ruta  /var/lib/docker/volumes no me aparece, me sale el siguiente error (observen tambien que me encuentro posicionado en mi carpeta de usuario):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El docker lo instale en windows y estoy usando WSL para poder usar linux con ubuntu. No entiendo porque no se encuentra la ruta especificada. agradezco mucho si alguno sabe porque. No estoy seguro si es que me toca ingresar a las carpetas de windows donde esta instalado docker para encontrar esa ruta y si es así como podría hacerlo desde linux?

Comment: Si hiciste la instalación de Docker en Windows, no vas a encontrar esa carpeta en Linux. Probablemente [este tutorial](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/windows/wsl/) te sirva.

Comment: Si necesitas acceder desde windows al sistema de archivos de windows esta montado en /mnt/c/user ... podrias probar y nos comentas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es que en Windows la ruta es diferente, no igual que Linux.
Escribas en el explorador de archivos de Windows:

Para Docker **Engine v20.10.16**: `\\wsl$\docker-desktop-data\data\docker\volumes`

Para Docker **Engine v19.03**: `\\wsl$\docker-desktop-data\version-pack-data\community\docker\volumes\`

¿Cómo se accede desde WSL?

1. En Windows CMD ejecutas
   `net use h: \\wsl$\docker-desktop-data`
   (crear un drive **h** apuntando a \wsl$\docker-desktop-data)
2. En terminal de Ubuntu ejecutas

   `sudo mkdir /mnt/docker`

   `sudo mount -t drvfs h: /mnt/docker`
   (crear un directorio /mnt/docker y montar **h** a /mnt/docker )

Ahora `cd /mnt/docker/data/docker/volumes` ya tienes todos

Comment: Gracias brother, en windows encontre la carpeta en la ruta que me indicaste para la version de docker 20.10.16, pero mira que necesito ir a esa carpeta desde el ubuntu y cuando lo hago moviendome a la siguiente dirección: /mnt/wsl/docker-desktop-data/data/docker..... no me aparece la carpeta docker en la terminal de ubuntu :(, aparece como vacia, sabes que puede estar pasando?

Comment: @Hugo de nada hermano, para la segunda  pregunta hagas siguiente 1) En Windows CMD ejecutas net use h: \\wsl$\docker-desktop-data 2) en terminal de Ubuntu ejecutas sudo mkdir /mnt/docker y también sudo mount -t drvfs h: /mnt/docker.  Ahora cd /mnt/docker/data/docker/volumes ya tienes todos